# Why does the current THD increase and voltage THD decrease when increasing the inverter switching frequency?

Tags: pwm, harmonics, thd

I have a three phase inverter model and I am investigating the effects of an increased switching frequency for pre-defined LC filter parameters. It is a simple MATLAB Simulink model: DC source, inverter, LC filter and constant value resistive load.

The voltage THD decreases when I compare figures for 4 kHz vs 6 kHz switching frequency, and I would expect that, but the current THD increases. Why is that happening?

*f*sw = 4 kHz

[image]

[image]

Sinusoidal PWM, modulation index = 0.95:

[image]

*f*sw = 6 kHz

[image]

[image]

Sinusoidal PWM, modulation index = 0.95:

[image]

Interestingly, for an 8 kHz switching frequency and all other model parameters stayed the same, the current THD is reduced:

*f*sw = 8 kHz

[image]

[image]

Sinusoidal PWM, modulation index = 0.95

[image]

CircuitLab abstract model is below.

[image: schematic]

<sup>[simulate this circuit](/plugins/schematics?image=http%3a%2f%2fi.stack.imgur.com%2fOAD99.png) – Schematic created using [CircuitLab](https://www.circuitlab.com/)</sup>

Update:

I am also using **common-mode capacitance** 300 nF and 15 Ohm resistance between the load neutral point and ground.

[image]

When I plot the impedance graph, I can see a peak at ~5.6 kHz. Changing the common-mode capacitance affects the impedance peak, and subsequently, line current THD. For both Ccm × 10 (3000 nF) and Ccm ÷ 10 (30 nF), the current TDH for a 4 kHz switching frequency is lower.

[image]